# Divide a finite measure set into two part of equal measure using one hyperplane in R^n.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The term "measure" here are all refer to Lebesgue measure.

A is a measurable set in $\mathbb R^n$ with finite measure, the goal is to prove that there exists a real number $r$ with $m(A \cap\{x:x_n<r\})=m(A\cap\{x:x_n>r\})$, where $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$ in $\mathbb R^n$.

I've tried to prove that measure of finite measure sets is a continuous function and use intermediate value theorem. I've done this for closed cubes, but encountered some problem when trying to prove this for general measurable sets. Also, I was wondering if there's a simpler way to do this. Any help or hint are very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve is equivalent to$${m(A \cap\{x:x_n<r\})\over m(A)}=\frac 12$$

To be able to use the IVT, it is enough to prove that $$\lim_\limits{r\to -\infty} m(A \cap\{x:x_n<r\})=0$$
and $$\lim_\limits{r\to +\infty} m(A \cap\{x:x_n<r\})=m(A)$$
but by symmetry any of these equalities will imply the other.

Now the second equality comes from the fact that the series $$\sum_\limits{k=-\infty}^\infty m(A\cap \{x:k<x_n\leq k+1\})$$

converges to $m(A)$ by the continuity from below, and the **increasing** function of $r$ $$m(A \cap\{x:x_n<r\})$$
can be sandwiched between partial sums of the above series.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! There's one last question of me:I how would you prove the m(A∩{x:xn<r}) is a continuous function of r?

Comment: Since the function is increasing It's enough to prove that the limits from the left are equal to the limits from the right. Now use continuity from above,  continuity from below,  and the fact that $ m (x_n=r)=0 $.

Comment: Could you please state which theorem are you using about monotone function and continuity?

Comment: @simplyconnecteddonut it's not a theorem, it's clear if you write it down, I think that given the level of the original question that should be clear.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your set is bounded, any hyperplane passing through the center of gravity of your set divides it into two parts of equal measure.

If it is unbounded, it depends if the center of gravity has finite coordinates.